# Ignore columns containing zeroes in each row and create a new object

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a list object as follows:

```
V1=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
V2=c(0,10,0,10,0,10,0,10)
V3=c(0,0,15,15,0,0,15,15)
V4=c(0,0,0,0,20,20,20,20)
V5=c(25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25)
zz_new=cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is for each row, get the numbers which are non-zeroes and then create a new object where I can store these values.

For eg. for the first row, I want to get 5 and 25. For the second row I want to get 5,10 and 25. For the 6th row, 5,10,20 and 25 and so on.

Note here that I do not want to delete any columns.

The Final output should be an object that looks like:

```
New_Variable
5,25
5,10,25
5,15,25
5,10,15,25
5,20,25
5,10,20,25
5,15,20,25
5,10,15,20,25
```

I wrote a function to do this:

```
zz_new_create=list()

for (i in 1:nrow(zz_new)){
  for (ii in 1:ncol(zz_new)){
    if (zz_new[i,ii]>0){
      zz_new_create[i,ii]=zz_new[i,ii]
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in zz_new_create[i, ii] <- zz_new[i, ii] : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `apply` here in row mode:

```
zz_new_create <- apply(zz_new, 1, function(x) { x[x!=0] })
```

Keep in mind that this generates a list of jagged (uneven) vectors, i.e. each entry in the list is a vector of some potentially different length.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. The jagged uneven vectors is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Done. I was trying to accept it before but apparently, I could not accept answers till a certain time had passed. Today I learned.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an add up to Tim's answer, if you'd like the result to be a vector with all the values separated by commas, just add the following:

```
New_variable = apply(zz_new, 1, function(x) { paste(x[x!=0],collapse=",") })
> New_variable
[1] "5,25"          "5,10,25"       "5,15,25"       "5,10,15,25"    "5,20,25"       "5,10,20,25"    "5,15,20,25"   
[8] "5,10,15,20,25"
```